# Is there an equivalent (or close) to numpy.loadtxt for julia?

Tags: python, numpy, io, julia

I'm trying to convert some of my python programs over to julia and one requires that I take in a values in the shape of a matrix from a txt file, then proceed to use the matrix for multiplication and such.

So is there any better way to input from a file and load a matrix in julia besides iterating over lines or character by character?

For example, a text file would look like

```
5 9
10 3
```

so my matrix would then be

```
[[5,9],
 [10,3]]
```

which I'd then use to multiply other matrices, etc.

I just got started with julia this week so I'm still doing my best to comb through the library and MIT sources. So far my best idea (assuming there is no equivalent to numpy.loadtxt) would be to load line by line into an array then just reshape it afterwards, but I want to make this as efficient as possible and that seems like a slow and not clean way of importing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [Readdlm()](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/stdlib/base/?highlight=readdlm#Base.readdlm). Check this [article](http://randyzwitch.com/julia-import-data/) for more details

```
julia> file="23 12 13 22
       15 61 17 10
       1 0 11 12"
```

You can read and transform it to an array `readdlm(IOBuffer(file))`, u can also force the array's items to be integers this way `readdlm(IOBuffer(file),int)`

```
julia> readdlm(IOBuffer(file))
3x4 Array{Float64,2}:
 23.0  12.0  13.0  22.0
 15.0  61.0  17.0  10.0
 1.0   0.0   11.0  12.0
```

Answer (score 0):

The `CSV.read()` function can also be used to read delimited files. The advantage of `CSV.read()` over `readdlm()` is that the `CSV.read()` is much faster for large files. To read, for example, the following,

```
julia> file = 
       """
       23 12 13 22
       15 61 17 10
       1 0 11 12
       """
```

The code would be,

```
julia> CSV.read(IOBuffer(file),delim=" ",ignorerepeated=true,header=false)
3×4 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ Column1 │ Column2 │ Column3 │ Column4 │
│     │ Int64   │ Int64   │ Int64   │ Int64   │
├─────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┤
│ 1   │ 23      │ 12      │ 13      │ 22      │
│ 2   │ 15      │ 61      │ 17      │ 10      │
│ 3   │ 1       │ 0       │ 11      │ 12      │
```

For small files, `readdlm()` is faster.

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> @btime CSV.read(IOBuffer(file),delim=" ",ignorerepeated=true,header=false);
  68.197 μs (185 allocations: 14.80 KiB)

julia> @btime readdlm(IOBuffer(file));
  2.465 μs (20 allocations: 40.70 KiB)
```

But for larger files, `CSV.read()` is much faster and efficient.

```
julia> @btime CSV.read(IOBuffer(file^100000),delim=" ",ignorerepeated=true,header=false);
  32.027 ms (230 allocations: 3.26 MiB)

julia> @btime readdlm(IOBuffer(file^100000));
  142.187 ms (3600025 allocations: 116.44 MiB)
```

It can be converted to an array as,

```
julia> dffile = CSV.read(IOBuffer(file),delim=" ",ignorerepeated=true,header=false);

julia> convert(Matrix, dffile)
3×4 Array{Int64,2}:
 23  12  13  22
 15  61  17  10
  1   0  11  12
```

Many other customizations can be done for reading different types of files and are detailed in the [documentation](https://juliadata.github.io/CSV.jl/stable/#CSV.read).